# Authenticate LDAP users in asynchronous mode with UnboundID LDAP SDK

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, credentials, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I need to Authenticate LDAP users in asynchronous mode. According to this [source](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/getting-started/asynchronous.html) we can not use simple bind request in asynchronous mode. If then, How can I authenticate a user by providing DN and password.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you need to authenticate in asynchronous mode?

Comment: Since asynchronous mode is a blocking call, performance (let's say number of authenticate requests per second) of the code will be reduced. but using asynchronous mode we will be able to increase the performance. Because there is no blocking call in asynchronous mode. That is why I need to use  asynchronous mode.

Answer (score 0):

As Neil indicated in his [response](http://sourceforge.net/p/ldap-sdk/discussion/1001257/thread/f7f00ed1/#d33b), the synchronous nature of LDAP BIND is mandated by the standard. Modern LDAP servers can handle tens of thousands of LDAP BIND operations / second, so performance concerns could hardly come into play.

Comment: Yes, There is no asynchronous implementation for bind request according to Neil's response to my concern on sourceforge. But, We can use several threads and same number of connections for each and every thread and then process bind request concurrently. But again this is a blocking call relative to each thread.

Comment: If the blocking nature is a problem for you, you can always create Executor-s that perform authentication out-of-band. However, you will not be able to use the bound identity until the LDAP bind completes.